# Every page i set as homepage doesnt fit to screen at mobile devices.But as page it does

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to use any page as homepage but whenever i set it as homepage it lacks responsiveness in mobile devices.Exactly as a page it has mobile view untill i set it as homepage where it doesnt fit to the screen .Please any help[IT LOOKS LIKE THIS]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPrDg.png

Comment: It is not related to WordPress. The theme (or page layout) you are using simply is not responsive.

Comment: well in every other page even the same if it isnt set as homepage it is responsive .So it does at the demo of the theme .It just happens only to me